# Unstable Ropsten transaction

Tags: ether, ropsten, ethers.js

I've been developing on top of Ropsten for a few days. The network becomes unbearably slow and has been causing network timeout very frequently. This problem is especially prominent during afternoons and evenings (Los Angeles time). I have tried to increase gasPrice as shown below:

```
Crafted TX:  {
  type: 2,
  chainId: 3,
  nonce: 91,
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "100000000000" },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "100000000000" },
  gasPrice: null,
  gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "1000000" },
  to: null,
  value: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  data: '...',
  accessList: [],
  hash: '0x7d632277c97447bbdaa5a1501c950c9a834be2fea3dce6af168e2b5f661a5a12',
  v: 1,
  r: '0x19e5c5f7c59f5bd0f12c4de3c86edf9a7b8f6caab9720096617cf7106a037334',
  s: '0x5bc3e9191bc12c46837cfee2bfd0d81b27fb1b758395996926676d6f00deb69c',
  from: '0x1782760f47eDd41648C418671a068CD3aC38c4dC',
  confirmations: 0,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

The Ropsten network is definitely working, since the Etherscan explorer shows a constant stream of mined blocks.

Here is how the transaction is sent:

```
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(...);

  let contract = await contractFactory.deploy({gasPrice: 100 * 1e9});
  console.log("Crafted TX: ", contract.deployTransaction);
  await contract.deployTransaction.wait();
  console.log("deployed contract: ", contract.address);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem went away by switching to use a different private key. I still don't understand why it happened. May be it is due to a bad nonce?

One interesting observation is that tons of stuck tx suddenly went through on [EtherScan](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x67d574b0218dca2eb790b5922c5da6a7b77e25a5?a=0x1782760f47eDd41648C418671a068CD3aC38c4dC).